# cannot read property '_withtask' of undefined vue

Tags: javascript

Tengo un evento click y me salta este error: cannot read property '_withtask' of undefined.

Mi código es:

```
<button v-on:click="addNode"></button>
```

Y como método:

```
export default Vue.extend({ 
    methods: { 
        addNode: function () { 
            this.gridOptions.api.deselectAll() 
            var newNode = { 'channel': 'canal', } 
            this.collection = this.prepend(newNode, this.collection) 
            this.gridOptions.rowData = this.collection
        } 
    }
}
```

Que básicamente lo que hace es añadir una nueva linea. Esta nueva linea se inserta, pero este error no me permite seguir interactuando con la aplicación.
El problema está en el prepend, he probado con push pero me da el mismo error...
¿Qué significa este error?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: añade completa tu instancia de Vue, es decir el modo en el que lo estas declarando

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto @AlfredoPaz?  export default Vue.extend({ })    Soy nueva en vue.

Comment: Creo que se refiere a que si el método es `addNode` añadas la clase entera a la que pertenece

Comment: Agregalo editando la pregunta, no en los comentarios, sino se complica un poco leerla para ayudarte!